# AngularJs ng-repeat not working for incremental viewmodel values using $index

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<ul id="DataLines">
    <li data-ng-repeat="dataLine in ViewModel.DataLines">
        <input type="text" value="{{dataLine}}" id="data{{ $index +1 }}"  data-ng-model="ViewModel.DataLine{{ $index +1 }}" required>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I am trying to achieve is add multiple input lines depending upon the DataLines. There are 3 main issues I am facing here but overall related to a bigger feature I am trying to get.

Firstly the view `data-ng-model="ViewModel.DataLine{{ $index +1 }}"` is not working..(Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected)

Secondly the input value is not getting prefilled `value="{{dataLine}}"`
Thirdly on ViewModel I dont have ViewModel.DataLine1, ViewModel.DataLine2, ViewModel.DataLine3 .... So I have no idea how to get the edited input values on the controller(ViewModel.DataLine1 ...its undefined on contrl)

I am not sure if I am handling this module correctly. Is there a better way of achieving this kind of result in Angular 2.0. Even some article or any blog which guides in this direction can help.
-Thanks

Comment: what does your `ViewModel.Datelines` angular scope array look like? Why are you using `$index+1` for each item instead of `$index`?

Comment: yes I agree it should be Index +1 for first line and then just Index for all the   remaining lines.. ViewModel.DataLines is List<String>

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to mix server code with javascript. There is no string list in javascript and angular  only works with javascript arrays and objects that are in controller scopes

Comment: yes I added the server model in previous comment.. will be an array of string ..But does the bigger picture seems correct to you ? Can the end result be achieved this way or there is some other approach to this kind of scenarios ?

Comment: what about difference between `ViewModel.DataLines` and `ViewModel.DataLine`? WHich is correct...will write answer but somethings wrong

Answer (score 0):

Notation for array and object variable keys in javascript is `[]`

Try doing:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="dataLine in ViewModel.DataLines">
    <input type="text" id="data{{ $index }}"  data-ng-model="ViewModel.DataLines[ $index ]" required>
</li>
```

Since you have `ng-model` you shouldn't need `valu` pointing to same array element

There is also a dsicrepeny between `ViewModel.DataLines` and `ViewModel.DataLine` in your code which i am uncertain about